# Wysiwyg editor errors

Tags: plugins, widgets, wysiwyg

Hi everybody I am having a prob with wordpress when in my themes and browse to widgets and they are not active and won't allow editing. This is a brand new WP install and even if I change my theme its still the same can't access widgets. This is sooo frustrating. Does ANYONE have an answer please. I also have a problem with my page composer on this site where it won't open the Text(html) Tab so all I can create is text posts and no hyperlinks. I have several site on this same hosting and none have these probs. Cant work it out any answers? Would be appreciated.

Comment: It is impossible to answer this as the issue is really just too localized. If you've switched themes and the propblem remains the same, you probably have conflict in one of the plugins you are using. Start of by clearing all caches (browser and plugin), set debug to true and use the developer tools in your browser to locate obvious bugs. Deactivate your plugins one by one until you find the culprit. If your issue is not relted to anything, reinstall Wordpress after taking a backup first

Comment: Thanks for your comment Its a brand new install no plugins added yet and all themes are not accessible in widgets even 2015 theme has frozen widgets. Will just have to delete again and try but how can a brand new install with no added plugins do this? I just don't understand why.